# Get the area for a gaussian line

Tags: python-2.7, gaussian

I am wondering if there is a way to get the area for a given gaussian line for python? I have my data for the gaussian but the only method I not in getting the area is to divide the data into bins and sum up the areas of the bins.

Comment: lines generally do not have area.... integrals of lines do....

Comment: I think was not clear. I mean the area under the curve that a Gaussian makes

Comment: You are correct. You were not clear.

Comment: What does "have my data for the gaussian" mean?

Comment: I have the data for x and y values to plot the gaussian

Comment: So do you need to fit a Gaussian to your data?  A Gaussian distribution is completely described by its mean and variance, so there's really only two numbers worth knowing.  (We might also need to locate it, so I suppose there are two more.)